# The markerview of mpandroidchart line chart

Tags: android, marker, mpandroidchart

I use `mpandroidchart` for my project, my chart is line chart, and its `markerview` is only one `Textview` to show the `yAxis` value. my `yAxis` value is float type, just like`1.4563,2.3659,8.2351`and so on.
when I show the `yAxis` value at my `makerview` ,it will show `1,4563` and I want show `1.4563`. As you see the dot changed comma, I don't know why this is ? I check my json data , it is really `1.4563`.

Comment: In some languages, comma is used instead of dot. Try to change your language to English from Settings and check result.

Comment: I have resolved, I override the method `formatNumber` and you will see `out[ind--] = ',' ` then changed the comma as a dot . it is  ok